# How front-enders should work with Razor View files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, frontend

I will start a new .Net MVC project with a small team. It have five members, two  back-end devs and three front-end devs.

The front-end members will work separately, building a html version of this project using tools like gulp/grunt, less/saas, jade and others frameworks.  They prefer to use editors like Sublime and will run interface tests in many differents devices in real time.

They not able to work with MVC specifically Razor view engine, so we need two repositories, one to front and another to back.The back-end developer in the process ever need to catch the built html and suit it in Razor MVC.

Any ideas how to improve this process? How can i reduce the technical gap between back devs and front devs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO you are trying too hard to accommodate the skills/desires of your team members.  You will not get good cohesion from the client side with the server side if you completely ignore Razor/CSHTML.  Your overall architecture/design should come first, and dictate these decisions.  Of course you would take your team's skills into consideration, such that you wouldn't make a team of Java developers adopt C++.  But you are taking this to an extreme by basically throwing consideration for design/architecture out of the window, and saying you will divide the application based on what your devs are willing to work with.

**My opinions aside**, you can make this work, but somewhat painfully.

For one, developing HTML apges first in a vacuum without consideration for interactions with the server is either going to result in very crippled interface that is more like static website from the 90s.  There are a few cases where you can build a single-page-application that's pure javascript with no AJAX requests, but these scenarios are very rare.

Therefore, you need to either build the server-side first, or have a design step that mocks up the page and talk through how it will work.

1) **Design a page and it's features, and how it interacts with the server.**  Identify what interactions are navigation actions, such as clicking a link to navigate to another page, versus those which are AJAX operations.  Do NOT implement HTML, that comes later.  As a team review what each dev mocks up and make sure they've thought through all of the interactions thoroughly.

From this, list what server side operations are needed in the controller for that page:

- agree upon URLs
- is it GET/POST
- is it AJAX
- whether it returns a page, partial HTML fragment, or JSON.
- what parameter names for each are and data types

2) Your backend developers create controllers, exposing actions based on agreed upon design.  CSHTML will for now be stubs and return nothing.

3) Your frontend developers create HTML/javascript to consume these.

They will be able to point ajax operations to the controllers, but they will need to mock what is returned since the Controllers don't know what HTML they should be returning yet.

4) Front end devs provide HTML to back end devs to incorporate into the project so that actions/partial views return the HTML or HTML fragments.

The problem is you are going to constantly be iterating through frontend devs giving HTML to backend devs to incorporate into the MVC project so that the actions that return HTML and or AJAX actions that return partial HTML fragments (PartialView) can be tested.

It makes for a very non-agile process.

You won't be able to take advantage of many frameworks for MVC which assume you are using Razor views/HTML helpers.  Many frameworks for compressing/bundling javascript/less/css which integrate well with MVC are not going to be viable.  You can still do this stuff, but you'll have a workflow that is not as smooth and will involve more hacking it together yourself.

I would like to point out that almost all javascript frameworks work great within CSHTML.  From the client side perspective, MVC/CSHTML doesn't introduce any strangeness that prevents you from building very interactive pages.  You can build a CSHTML page that is pure HTML and javascript, and makes AJAX calls to controllers, but trying to take that outside of the MVC project is going to cripple the development workflow.  Designing and implementing an interactive page requires alot of consideration for how the actions on the server side are implemented.

Comment: Thanks!!! Good vision and helped me.